QGIS: Colour Ramp for the height of bars
The map shows the number of population on 1x1km squares (vector data). However, I would like the colour to change to yellow as the size of the bars increases. (So not the whole bar, but a colour gradient from blue to yellow) I would use these colours: #114256 and #efce1c being the highest with 1900


The Vieidis color palette comes pre,-installed in QGIS: https://www.thinkingondata.com/something-about-viridis-library/

yes but how do I make it appear depending on the length of the bar

Without more information about your settings, it's difficult to know what you have

Can you share your dataset?

there is no finished data set, as I have calculated the values as a percentage using municipality inhabitants and areas (the data set from World Pop Hub Population would also be possible, but the data set does not correspond to my task) So I'll send the layer: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mImCXj9P2eypTR-JjR_pkcbspzmb0fuM/view?usp=sharing
The important chart is the last one (was too lazy to delete the other ones)
For the properties: Form: vertical line; stroke width: 0,5mm, Anchor point: Buttom; Opacity: 30%

Can you screenshot your properties menu with the symbology (or 3d symbology) tab selected?

hey, sure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VFa5fXPyxsoMfzohEaDN04pL4e8-U8mr/view?usp=sharing

We can achieve this outcome by using polygons for each point and altering the gradient for each polygon based on a value.
The taller the column is the more yellow it becomes.

In this example I have used polygons which get one of 5 different gradients based on their values.

Each point is extruded into a polygon column based on an input value "Faktor*Be4_sum"
Depending on the (value) of the line it gets a certain colour ramp

To achieve this we need to do 2 things:

Create a Geometry Generated Polygon column

Change the top Colour of the color ramp for each polygon based on the value "Faktor*Be4_sum"



single_sided_buffer(
make_line( make_point(x($geometry), y($geometry)),
  make_point(x($geometry) , y($geometry)+(("Faktor*Be4_sum"+0.001)*10))
  )
  ,150,0,2)


CASE
WHEN "Faktor*Be4_sum" <= (maximum("Faktor*Be4_sum")-minimum("Faktor*Be4_sum"))/10 THEN '#114256'
WHEN "Faktor*Be4_sum" <= ((maximum("Faktor*Be4_sum")-minimum("Faktor*Be4_sum"))/10)*2 THEN '#29514F'
WHEN "Faktor*Be4_sum" <= ((maximum("Faktor*Be4_sum")-minimum("Faktor*Be4_sum"))/10)*4 THEN '#5B7042'
WHEN "Faktor*Be4_sum" <= ((maximum("Faktor*Be4_sum")-minimum("Faktor*Be4_sum"))/10)*6 THEN '#8C8F35'
WHEN "Faktor*Be4_sum" <= ((maximum("Faktor*Be4_sum")-minimum("Faktor*Be4_sum"))/10)*8 THEN '#BDAE28'
WHEN "Faktor*Be4_sum" > ((maximum("Faktor*Be4_sum")-minimum("Faktor*Be4_sum"))/10)*8 THEN '#efce1c'
ELSE '#252525'
END

We can see here that each point is converted to a polygon with its own color ramp:


Thank you very much. That's what I was looking for!

If I understand correctly, you want to make the color ramp appear within each individual feature, and to the best of my knowledge this is not possible in the current version of QGIS.
However, you can get close to the desired effect as follows:

Set the symbology type to 'Graduated'
Set value field to 'Faktor*Be4_sum'
Choose (or create) color ramp
Click 'Classify' Button
Click 'Symbol' Dropdown
Click 'Configure Symbol
Click the size equation settings --> edit
Edit the equation as shown & apply settings




Result:

